# How to fire touch events for browsers with wordpress and IOS

Tags: javascript, ios, wordpress, plugins

I'm working on a wordpress site, and I'm trying to get touch events to work, I'm currently using a simple touch start event like this:

```
$(".element").bind("touchstart", function() { $(".element").hide(); });
```

Where element is just a button tag.
My problem is that the events are not firing on any browser for IOS, even though they are working correctly on android.
I'm lead to believe that wordpress might have something to do with this, because I've tried the same events on web pages without wordpress, and they all work fine.

Comment: Can you check the listeners bound to touchstart on this element in web developer tools? It's possible some plugin intercepts this in `capture` phase, incorrectly stopping event propagation for some reason.